# Issue with if-else statements

Tags: python, testing

This is what I've input:

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer):
    if 6 > 5:
        return 1
    elif  4 < 5:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

print greater_less_equal_5(4)
print greater_less_equal_5(5)
print greater_less_equal_5(6)
```

and gave me this note

> Oops, try again. It looks like your function output 1 instead of -1
>   when answer is 3. Make sure you filled in the if and elif statements
>   correctly!

and this is what came up in the upper right display:

```
>1
>1
>1
>None
```

No matter how I change around the numbers and the `>`/`<` I've even tried `==` and `!=` it still outputs `1 1 1 None`.

I've searched around for any possible tips and seen others stuck on the same problem as me and when I tried their solves I then get:

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer):
    if > 5:
        return 1
    elif  < 5:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

print greater_less_equal_5(4)
print greater_less_equal_5(5)
print greater_less_equal_5(6)
```

and the output is:

```
File "python", line 2
    if > 5:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is this test rigged to always output a failed result to make me pay for pro and ask for their help?

And the hint given for this is:

> Make sure the if and elif statements end with colons :
>
> Your code should look something like:
>
> ```
> if EXPRESSION:
>     do something
> elif OTHER EXPRESSION:
>     do something
> else:
>     do something
> ```

Am I just missing something horribly basic?

Comment: Please edit your answer and use code tags.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to solve an online challenge on an online platform, in which case it is prudent to mention what the stated problem is specifically about (see [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: You're missing something elemental. Your function never references the argument (poorly) named _answer_ it's passed...so it always does the same thing based on the numbers you've hard-coded into it. In other words, `6` since is always going to be greater than `5`, so it always returns the value `1`.

Comment: You should review [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), especially the sections "[The `if` Statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if)" and "[Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)".  While [basic beginner questions are allowed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265565/downvoting-stupid-simple-questions) on SO, the official tutorial(s) for a language are an obvious resource that you should consult before asking here.

Comment: sry for being so noob. I only started checking out this a couple days ago when trying to figure out how to make a twitch bot and figured this might be fun to learn. This being my first post here I am not very familiar with tag ettiquette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed missing something basic - namely, that the output of your function doesn't depend on `answer` at all. No matter what you feed in as `answer`, because `6 > 5` is always `True`, it will always return the result of *that* case.

What you need is

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer):
    if answer > 5:
        return 1
    elif answer < 5:          
        return -1
    elif answer == 5:
        return 0
```

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. I actually figured this out within like twenty mins of posting this. I was having problems forgetting to put answer in so it would reference the expression just forgot to remove the posting.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing 'answer' variable for expression, which you pass into your function

```
def greater_less_equal_5(answer):
    if answer > 5:
        return 1
    elif  answer < 5:          
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

print greater_less_equal_5(4)
print greater_less_equal_5(5)
print greater_less_equal_5(6)
```